# EllipticF reduction

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions, nonlinear

Is it possible to reduce the following Z to Legendre form Elliptic integral of the First kind?

$$ \int \dfrac {\sec u\; du } {\sqrt{ (1-  {(\nu  \tan u)}^2 }} ..(1*)$$

With substitution of $ \tan u = t, $  I get it into ArcSin type:

$$ \int \dfrac {dt } {\sqrt{  (1-  {(\nu \;  t)}^2)} }  ...(2*) $$

EDIT 2:

After the above error pointed out by bbgodfrey is corrected, (1*) assumes form:

$$ \int \dfrac {dt } {\sqrt{(1+ t^2) (1- {(\nu   t)}^2)} }  ...(2*) $$

which still needs to be adjusted to get to classical form.

Mathematica evaluation

```
DSolve[ Z'[u] == Sec[u]/Sqrt[ 1 - (nu Tan[u])^2 ], Z, u]
```

results in $ EllipticF\; [u, 1 + \nu^2] $. Obviously I am missing something but cannot

find what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two integrals are not equivalent, as can be seen from

```
D[Tan[u], u]
(* Sec[u]^2 *)
```

The transformation from `t` to `u` takes the second integral from

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - (nu t)^2], t]
```

to

```
Integrate[Sec[u]^2/Sqrt[1 - (nu Tan[u])^2], u]
```